# j2me lwuit list take the same cell background

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40

I am making a list that has persons and every ones rate as a cell background 
the list gives every cell the same rate background but when scroll the list up or down the cell that I'm dragging take it's real rate background but other cells stay the same rate background image
I'm using nokia s40 full touch emulator 
This is the code that I'm using for the cell renderer

```
    list.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {

        public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list,
                Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) {
            String rate = "";

            rate = Transportation.getDriverRate(value.toString(),
                    CityListForm.selectedCity);
            rate = (Integer.parseInt(rate)) > 25 ? "" + 5 : ""
                    + Integer.parseInt(rate) / 5;
            rate = "/" + rate + ".png";
            Image image = null;
            Label label = null;
            try {

                image = (Image.createImage(rate));
                System.out.println(rate);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            label = new Label();

            label.getStyle().setBgImage(image);
            label.setText(value.toString());
            label.getStyle().setAlignment(RIGHT);
            label.setTextPosition(RIGHT);
            Style style = label.getStyle();
            style.setBgColor(16777215);
            style.setFgColor(0);

            label.setPreferredH(42);
            return label;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `List.setMutableRendererBackgrounds(true);`

Answer (score 0):

thnx for the answer 
i solved it by making a container and butting two labels inside it one for the value and the other for the rate icon and give the container a layout and return the container in the getListCellRendererComponent() method